# iterating through the days of a month when DayLight saving changes

Tags: c#, timezone

I'm creating a list of days that start at the beginning of the last day of the month and that end the first day of the following month, all in UTC. For this month (October 2013), a user in  the French timezone has his month start UTC date `CalendarMonthStartUTC` on 9/30 @ 10PM and his end date `CalendarMonthEndUTC` in UTC is 10/31 @ 11PM.

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
DateTime StartTime = CalendarMonthStartUTC;
DateTime EndTime = new DateTime()

while (StartTime < CalendarMonthEndUTC)
{
     EndTime = StartTime.AddHours(24);
     ... do something here
     StartTime = StartTime.AddHours(24);
}
```

This loop works fine for all months of the year except in October because of the DayLight saving change, which creates an OBO bug because the loop iterates by adding 24 hours at each iteration.
I'm wondering how to modify my loop so that it works regardless of the DayLight saving days.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: The last valid DateTime in October is one tick before November 1st.  UTC is *not* affected by daylight saving changes, there is no bug.

Comment: @HansPassant: no the bug occurs when a day is longer than 24 hours (ie. when an hour is added when the daylight saving period ends) and I'm only adding 24 hours.

Comment: No, UTC days are always 24 hours.  When you convert the UTC datetime to local time then you can end up with days of more or less due to the DST change.

Comment: If you want to account for specific hour-intervals (and performing intermediate calculations for each interval, as in your code), you have to bring daylight savings into account (and a code on the lines of the answer I wrote); but as far as you are just interested in whole days, Ergwun's approach is clearly better. I did also get focused on the hours and lost the true point here (the code I wrote works fine but is unnecessarily complicated).

Comment: Well... unless the specific hour for each day (StartTime and EndTime) matters to you (not sure what you are doing in the "//... do something here" part), that is, if despite adding days you want to know what happens at the "hour level". If you need more control on what happens in each iteration (and account for DayLight Savings every time), just let me know and I can undelete my answer. As you have asked your question, Ergwun's answer seems to be the most adequate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just work in local time, and convert to UTC at the end?

If you want to perform the calculation for the timezone currently set on the local machine then you can do this:

```
        DateTime calendarMonth = new DateTime(2013, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
        DateTime startDay = calendarMonth.AddDays(-1);
        DateTime endDay = calendarMonth.AddMonths(1);

        while (startDay <= endDay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(startDay + " = " + startDay.ToUniversalTime());
            startDay = startDay.AddDays(1);
        }
```

If you want to calculate it for a given timezone regardless of the local machine settings then you do the conversion to UTC like this:

```
        var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
        var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startDay, timeZone));
```

Comment: But if the OP needs to perform intermediate calculations (between startDate and endDate) and the DayLight Saving Times are not accounted for, an error would be accumulated, isn't it?

Comment: @varocarbas Not sure what kind of calculations you are talking about? Once you've generated the list of UTC times then you can use UTC time for interval calculations etc. as required.

Comment: I read your code now more properly and I was mistaken: you are adding days by ignoring the time issues!! This is a better solution, no doubt. I was so focused on the hours that I misread your code, sorry. +1 for you :) I delete my answer because does only make sense by bringing specific hours into consideration; for whole days, yours is undoubtedly better.

Comment: Working in local time is the correct general approach, but this particular code is only good if it is running on the user's computer, such as in a desktop or mobile app.  If it is in any way running on a *server*, such as in a web application, you should avoid `DateTimeKind.Local` and `.ToUniversalTime()`, and use the methods on the `TimeZoneInfo` class instead.

Comment: @MattJohnson Good point. I had assumed it was for the timezone specified on the local machine. I've added a snippet for converting from a specified other time zone's local time.